# Is it possible to show my own avatar when in a Skype conversation?

Tags: conversion, skype, avatar

I want to record Skype conversation and need myself showed in Skype conversation GUI - at the moment we can see every one except ourselves.

Is it possible to view my own avatar in the conversation avatar list? If it is, please show me how.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Do you want to replace the **other** user's avatar?

Comment: @ChrisF: No Chris. I want to include my avatar in the converstion.

Comment: He wants to see himself.